# WP custom_pre_get_posts breaks theme

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

I added this code weeks ago, but it suddenly stopped working last night, how could that be? It works fine on a local server, but not on a shared host. Local is running PHP 5.5.3 and host was running 5.4, but I put in a request to upgrade that specific subdomain to 5.5 just now in case that was at play.

Working with a child theme. The parent theme creates a custom post type called Portfolio, with the slug for all posts in it as /portfolio-item/. In my child theme, I added two things: 1. A new custom post type called Hidden Pages, and I used a code I found online that removes the slug, so it's just domain.com/page-name. 2. I added more code referring to the Portfolio type, which also removes the slug.

Everything was working perfectly, but all of a sudden, all standard pages 404 (and are hidden on the backend, but not in the database, this is not a database problem!), and the Portfolio posts are magically moved to the blog (regular standard posts). If you comment out the custom_pre_get_posts line (132), the problem resolves. But the client needs the urls to be clean without the slug. So I do not want to leave it as-is.

Here is the functions.php for the child theme:

```
<?php

function evol_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/css/style.css' ); 

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'evol_child_scripts' );

/*function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Hidden Pages'
    );
    register_post_type( 'hidden', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
*/

/**
 * Register a custom post type but don't do anything fancy
 */
register_post_type( 'hidden', array( 'label' => 'Hidden Pages', 'public' => true, 'capability_type' => 'post',  'show_ui' => true, 'query_var' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ) ) );
/**
 * Remove the slug from published post permalinks. Only affect our CPT though.
 */
function vipx_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'hidden' ) ) 
        || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $post_link;

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vipx_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Some hackery to have WordPress match postname to any of our public 
 * post types. All of our public post types can have /post-name/ as 
 * the slug, so they better be unique across all posts. Typically core 
 * only accounts for posts and pages where the slug is /post-name/
 */
function vipx_parse_request_tricksy( $query ) {

    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
        || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, 
    // otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'hidden', 'page' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vipx_parse_request_tricksy' );

function remove_search_filter () {
    remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'tr_search_filter' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_search_filter');

function remove_icons() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'icons' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_icons' );

function tr_widgets_init_2() {

    if ( ot_get_option( 'tr_sidebars' ) ) :
        $tr_sidebars = ot_get_option( 'tr_sidebars' );
        foreach ( $tr_sidebars as $tr_sidebar ) {
            register_sidebar( array(
                'id' => $tr_sidebar["id"],
                'name' => $tr_sidebar["title"],
                'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h6 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h6>',
            ));
        }
    endif;
};
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'tr_widgets_init_2' );


 add_filter('post_type_link','custom_post_type_link', 10, 3); 
    function custom_post_type_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) { 

        $url_components = parse_url($permalink); 
        $post_path = $url_components['path']; 
        $post_name = end((explode('/', trim($post_path, '/'))));

        if(!empty($post_name)) { 
            switch($post->post_type) { 
                case 'portfolio': 
                    $permalink = str_replace($post_path, '/' . $post_name . '/', $permalink); 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        return $permalink; 
    } 

    function custom_pre_get_posts($query) { 
        global $wpdb; 

        if(!$query->is_main_query()) { 
            return; 
        } 

        $post_name = $query->get('name'); 
        $post_type = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT post_type FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_name = %s LIMIT 1', $post_name ) ); 

        switch($post_type) { 
            case 'portfolio': 
                $query->set('portfolio', $post_name); 
                $query->set('post_type', $post_type); 
                $query->is_single = true; 
                $query->is_page = false; 
            break; 
        } 

        return $query; 
     } 


     add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_pre_get_posts');

function fb_add_search_box ( $items, $args ) {

    // only on primary menu
    if( 'primary' === $args -> theme_location )
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-search">' . get_search_form( FALSE ) . '</li>';

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'fb_add_search_box', 10, 2 );

// Callback function to insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function my_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
// Register our callback to the appropriate filter
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2');

// Callback function to filter the MCE settings
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  
    // Define the style_formats array
    $style_formats = array(  
        // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
        array(  
            'title' => 'Image Text', 
            'block' => 'p',  
            'classes' => 'image-text',     
        ),  
        array(  
            'title' => 'Image Text no Overlay', 
            'block' => 'p',  
            'classes' => 'image-text-2',     
        ),  
        array(  
             'title' => 'w/ gray background', 
            'inline' => 'span',  
            'exact' => true,    
             'classes' => 'gray-background', 
        ),  
        array(  
             'title' => 'w/ white background', 
            'inline' => 'span',  
            'exact' => true,    
             'classes' => 'white-background', 
        ),  
        array(  
            'title' => 'Image Text no Indent', 
            'block' => 'p',  
            'classes' => 'image-text-3',     
        ), 
        array(  
             'title' => 'Button', 
            'inline' => 'a',  
            'exact' => true,    
             'classes' => 'button small', 
        ),  
        array(  
            'title' => 'Blog Image Caption', 
            'block' => 'p',  
            'classes' => 'caption',     
        ), 
        array(  
             'title' => 'Signature', 
            'inline' => 'span',  
            'exact' => true,    
             'classes' => 'sign', 
        ),
    );  
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

    return $init_array;  

} 
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init' 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

This is the parent functions.php:

```
<?php

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_theme_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'themerain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list' ) );
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Navigation Menu' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'portfolio', 740, 540, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'tr_theme_setup' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Sets up the content width value based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 780;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Load Theme Options
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'ot_show_pages', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'ot_show_new_layout', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'ot_theme_mode', '__return_true' );
load_template( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'option-tree/ot-loader.php' );
load_template( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'includes/theme-options.php' );
load_template( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'includes/meta-boxes.php' );
load_template( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'includes/theme-functions.php' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Register Sidebars
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'id' => 'sidebar',
        'name' => 'Default Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));

    register_sidebar( array(
        'id' => 'footer-sidebar',
        'name' => 'Footer Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));

    if ( ot_get_option( 'tr_sidebars' ) ) :
        $tr_sidebars = ot_get_option( 'tr_sidebars' );
        foreach ( $tr_sidebars as $tr_sidebar ) {
            register_sidebar( array(
                'id' => $tr_sidebar["id"],
                'name' => $tr_sidebar["title"],
                'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h6 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h6>',
            ));
        }
    endif;
};
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'tr_widgets_init' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Register and load CSS & jQuery
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/icons.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/magnific-popup.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.custom.js', 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.flexslider.min.js', 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'validation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js', 'jquery' );
    if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tr_enqueue_scripts' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Load Widgets
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

include( "includes/widget-recent-projects.php" );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Configure Pagination
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_pagination() {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $pages = '';
    $total = 1;
    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if ( ! $current = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) $current = 1;
    $args['base'] = str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) );
    $args['total'] = $max;
    $args['current'] = $current;
    $args['end_size'] = 1;
    $args['mid_size'] = 3;
    $args['prev_text'] = '<i class="fa-angle-left"></i> Previous';
    $args['next_text'] = 'Next <i class="fa-angle-right"></i>';
    $args['type'] = 'list';
    if ( $max > 1 ) echo '<div id="pagination">';
    if ( $total == 1 && $max > 1 );
    echo $pages . paginate_links( $args );
    if ( $max > 1 ) echo '</div>';
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Configure Excerpt
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' ...';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Configure Tag Cloud
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tag_cloud_filter($args = array()) {
   $args['smallest'] = 12;
   $args['largest'] = 12;
   $args['unit'] = 'px';
   return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args', 'tag_cloud_filter', 90);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Exclude Pages from Search
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_search_filter( $filter ) {
    if ( $filter->is_search ) {
        $filter->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    }
    return $filter;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'tr_search_filter' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Add Portfolio Post Types
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_portfolio() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio',
        'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Item',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolio Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Portfolio Items',
        'view_item' => 'View Portfolio Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Portfolio Items',
        'not_found' =>  'No Portfolio Items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolio Items found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-item' ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

    register_taxonomy(
        "portfolio-category", array( "portfolio" ), array(
            "hierarchical" => true,
            "label" => "Portfolio Categories",
            "singular_label" => "Portfolio Categories",
            "rewrite" => true,
            "query_var" => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_portfolio' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Add Gallery Post Types
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tr_gallery() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Gallery',
        'singular_name' => 'Gallery Item',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Gallery Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Gallery Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Gallery Items',
        'view_item' => 'View Gallery Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Gallery Items',
        'not_found' =>  'No Gallery Items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Gallery Items found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'gallery-item' ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );

    register_taxonomy(
        "gallery-category", array( "gallery" ), array(
            "hierarchical" => true,
            "label" => "Gallery Categories",
            "singular_label" => "Gallery Categories",
            "rewrite" => true,
            "query_var" => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_gallery' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Add a Custom Taxonomy to the Post Class
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function custom_portfolio_post_class( $classes, $class, $ID ) {
    $taxonomy = 'portfolio-category';
    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, $taxonomy );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) $terms as $order => $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) ) {
                $classes[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'custom_portfolio_post_class', 10, 3 );

function custom_gallery_post_class( $classes, $class, $ID ) {
    $taxonomy = 'gallery-category';
    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, $taxonomy );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) $terms as $order => $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) ) {
                $classes[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'custom_gallery_post_class', 10, 3 );

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Register the Required Plugins
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/plugin-activation.php';

function tr_register_required_plugins() {

    $plugins = array(
        array(
            'name'                  => 'Rain Shortcodes',
            'slug'                  => 'rain-shortcodes',
            'source'                => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/plugins/rain-shortcodes.zip',
            'required'              => true,
            'version'               => '',
            'force_activation'      => false,
            'force_deactivation'    => false,
            'external_url'          => '',
        )
    );

    $theme_text_domain = 'tgmpa';

    $config = array(
        'domain'            => $theme_text_domain,
        'default_path'      => '',
        'parent_menu_slug'  => 'themes.php',
        'parent_url_slug'   => 'themes.php',
        'menu'              => 'install-required-plugins',
        'has_notices'       => true,
        'is_automatic'      => true,
        'message'           => '',
        'strings'           => array(
            'page_title'                                => __( 'Install Required Plugins', $theme_text_domain ),
            'menu_title'                                => __( 'Install Plugins', $theme_text_domain ),
            'installing'                                => __( 'Installing Plugin: %s', $theme_text_domain ), // %1$s = plugin name
            'oops'                                      => __( 'Something went wrong with the plugin API.', $theme_text_domain ),
            'notice_can_install_required'               => _n_noop( 'This theme requires the following plugin: %1$s.', 'This theme requires the following plugins: %1$s.' ),
            'notice_can_install_recommended'            => _n_noop( 'This theme recommends the following plugin: %1$s.', 'This theme recommends the following plugins: %1$s.' ),
            'notice_cannot_install'                     => _n_noop( 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to install the %s plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin installed.', 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to install the %s plugins. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugins installed.' ),
            'notice_can_activate_required'              => _n_noop( 'The following required plugin is currently inactive: %1$s.', 'The following required plugins are currently inactive: %1$s.' ),
            'notice_can_activate_recommended'           => _n_noop( 'The following recommended plugin is currently inactive: %1$s.', 'The following recommended plugins are currently inactive: %1$s.' ),
            'notice_cannot_activate'                    => _n_noop( 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to activate the %s plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin activated.', 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to activate the %s plugins. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugins activated.' ),
            'notice_ask_to_update'                      => _n_noop( 'The following plugin needs to be updated to its latest version to ensure maximum compatibility with this theme: %1$s.', 'The following plugins need to be updated to their latest version to ensure maximum compatibility with this theme: %1$s.' ),
            'notice_cannot_update'                      => _n_noop( 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to update the %s plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin updated.', 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to update the %s plugins. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugins updated.' ),
            'install_link'                              => _n_noop( 'Begin installing plugin', 'Begin installing plugins' ),
            'activate_link'                             => _n_noop( 'Activate installed plugin', 'Activate installed plugins' ),
            'return'                                    => __( 'Return to Required Plugins Installer', $theme_text_domain ),
            'plugin_activated'                          => __( 'Plugin activated successfully.', $theme_text_domain ),
            'complete'                                  => __( 'All plugins installed and activated successfully. %s', $theme_text_domain ),
            'nag_type'                                  => 'updated'
        )
    );
    tgmpa( $plugins, $config );

}
add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'tr_register_required_plugins' );

?>
```

When wp_debug is set to true, this returns:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in    
[path redacted]/functions.php on line 97
```

This refers to this line:

```
$post_name = end(explode('/', trim($post_path, '/')));
```

This is still in the error log, but after a change, it is not there on the admin side, does that mean it's fixed?

Child theme code is from here: https://gist.github.com/stefanbc/6620151 and http://www.markwarddesign.com/2014/02/remove-custom-post-type-slug-permalink/

So, if anyone knows how to modify this file to revert everything back to working perfectly, that'd be great. We are days away from launch, actually. Eep. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with Wordpress as the error stated, It's all pure PHP. You should make a little change in that line (*wrapping `explode()` with parenthesis*):

```
$post_name = end((explode('/', trim($post_path, '/'))));
```

Comment: Hi Revo! Thanks so much, that did indeed remove the error, so now we're error free. But it didn't fix the problem unfortunately. Still 404ing on pages which are still messed up. Any next steps? (And should I update the code above to reflect this change, or should I leave it?)

Comment: @Alicia Set both `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`. However you enabled WP_DEBUG already, you need to add this line after that: `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`. Then go to your website for logs to be created and check the `debug.log` log file inside the `/wp-content/` directory. It's better to add an update to your post too.

Comment: Ok, if you mean the error_log, here is the error: 
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare vipx_remove_cpt_slug() (previously declared in evol-child/functions.php:26) in evol/functions.php on line 294
This is referring to the fact that I guess I must have also added that section to the parent theme's functions, too.

Comment: @Alicia So that's there! You've that function already in parent template declared, there is no need for redeclaration.

Comment: Ok problem is I just looked and... it's not there. Let me add the parent functions.php.

Comment: Added! So maybe the problem is that I am trying to remove the slug for two different post types. Maybe we can consolidate the code, but I've no idea how. The portfolio and hidden pages types should have identical functionality, I just want them to be managed separately, if that helps at all.

Comment: (That must be an old error from when I was troubleshooting and copying and pasting a lot of stuff. Sorry about that!)

Comment: @Alicia Hmmm, How about wrapping that function and its following `add_filter` with `if(!function_exists('vipx_remove_cpt_slug')) { ... }`?

Comment: I don't think that was the problem. I think, as I said, that error might be old. While troubleshooting I might have had that code in both the parent and child at the same time by accident. Currently it seems to still be printing the error on line 97 error though! We can take this to chat if you'd like?

Comment: @Alicia Sorry you don't have enough reputation to move in a chat.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize. Can contact me offsite, or we can keep going here. Thanks for the help so far by the way! So far not closer to fixing though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to this problem given my level of PHP and not wanting to rewrite code that involves both a parent and child theme's functions. I ended up removing all code that attempted to remove the slug. I crossed my fingers and installed this outdated plugin and it worked. So for anyone for future reference, I suppose you can avoid code and just use this instead!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/